# Python pdb not breaking in files properly?

Tags: python, pdb

I wish I could provide a simple sample case that occurs using standard library code, but unfortunately it only happens when using one of our in-house libraries that in turn is built on top of sql alchemy.

Basically, the problem is that this `break` command:

```
(Pdb) print sqlalchemy.engine.base.__file__
/prod/eggs/SQLAlchemy-0.5.5-py2.5.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py

(Pdb) break /prod/eggs/SQLAlchemy-0.5.5-py2.5.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:946
```

Is just being totally ignored, it seems, by `pdb`. As in, even though I am *positive* the code is being hit (both because I can see log messages, and because I've used `sys.settrace` to check which lines in which files are being hit), `pdb` is just not breaking there.

I suspect that somehow the use of an egg is confusing `pdb` as to what files are being used (I can't reproduce the error if I use a non-egg'ed library, like `pickle`; there everything works fine).

It's a shot in the dark, but has anyone come across this before?

Comment: Can you check if base.py is a real file, or is it in a zip

Comment: It's definitely readable and not zipped.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if somehow there's an old .pyc that can't be deleted because of permissions being messed up. Nuke all of the .pycs in your python-path, and see if that helps.

[This blog post](http://rpatterson.net/blog/emacs-pdb-and-eggs) might be related to your trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I don't suppose this is yet another problem caused by setuptools? I ask because I notice the ".egg" in that path...

Answer (score 0):

What version of python are running?  I observe similar behavior on python 2.7.3.  Curiously, I do *not* see the same behavior on ipython 0.12.1.

In python 2.7.3, the debugger and the stack trace get the point where an exception occurred wrong.

In ipython 0.12.1, the debugger and the stack trace get the point where the exception occurs is correct, but once the exception occurs, then the program exits, which makes post mortem debugging difficult.